# i am trying to validate my email field on form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi guys please help me to solve my problem.  Actually i am trying to validate my email field on form using javascript and post an ajax request to check if that email exists or not but my javascript function does not wait until the ajax response and every time it returns false. I want to be return true when email does not exist...

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //global vars
    var form = $("#signupForm");
    var email = $("#email");
    var email_error = $("#invalid");

    //On blur
   // userEmail.blur(validateEmail);

    //On Submitting
    form.submit(function(){

        if(validateEmail()){
            alert("submit true");
            return true;
        }else{
        alert("submit false");
            return false;
            }
    });


    function validateEmail(){
        //if it's NOT valid
        alert("In email");
        var a = $("#email").val();
        var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

        if(email.val() == ""){
            email_error.html("Please enter your email ");
            return false;
        }
        //if it's valid email
        else if(filter.test(a)==false){
            email_error.html("Please enter Valid email address");
            return false;
        }
        else if(filter.test(a)==true){alert("elseif");
        var baseUrl = '<?= base_url() ?>';

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: baseUrl+"index.php/index/validateUserEmail",
                    data: "useremail="+$("#email").val(),
                    success: function(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                    if(msg == "1")
                        {
                            $("#tick_cross").fadeIn("slow").html('<img src="'+baseUrl+'images/cross.png" />');
                            $("#emailValidate").val("1");  
                            email_error.html("This email-Id already exists!");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            $("#tick_cross").fadeIn("slow").html('<img src="'+baseUrl+'images/tick.png" />');
                            $("#emailValidate").val("0");
                            email_error.html(" ");
                            alert("alok");
                            return true;
                        }


                    }
                });

        }

        else{
        email_error.html(" ");
        return true;
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: it will not work like that because of async nature of ajax, you need to use a callback to solve it

Comment: Try setting the option async : false as in here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re

Comment: FYI, `async` is deprecated post `v1.8`

Comment: thanks for reply arun but how i use it here ...??

Comment: Comment turned back to answer because that is what it is, an answer!

Comment: You need to set the option async : false as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re

Comment: As Arun said, there is no need to manipulate the sync param, Ajax is async and that the basic and good behaviour (if you are using sync request, the browser will freeze waiting for response...Bad!). When the user submit the form, you run your ajax call and return directly false to stop the propagation of the event and prevent the default behaviour (in this case, a submit). Later, when the AJAX response comme back, if the email is good, submit the form by the code (which will not run again the check). That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // global vars
    var form = $("#signupForm");
    var email = $("#email");
    var email_error = $("#invalid");

    // On blur
    // userEmail.blur(validateEmail);

    // On Submitting
    form.submit(function() {

                validateEmail(function(flag) {
                            if (flag) {
                                alert("submit true");
                                form[0].submit();
                            } else {
                                alert("submit false");
                            }

                        });
                return false;
            });

    function validateEmail(callback) {
        // if it's NOT valid
        alert("In email");
        var a = $("#email").val();
        var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

        if (email.val() == "") {
            email_error.html("Please enter your email ");
            callback(false);
        }
        // if it's valid email
        else if (filter.test(a) == false) {
            email_error.html("Please enter Valid email address");
            callback(false);
        } else if (filter.test(a) == true) {
            alert("elseif");
            var baseUrl = '<?= base_url() ?>';

            $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : baseUrl + "index.php/index/validateUserEmail",
                        data : "useremail=" + $("#email").val(),
                        success : function(msg) {
                            alert(msg);
                            if (msg == "1") {
                                $("#tick_cross").fadeIn("slow")
                                        .html('<img src="' + baseUrl
                                                + 'images/cross.png" />');
                                $("#emailValidate").val("1");
                                email_error
                                        .html("This email-Id already exists!");
                                callback(false);
                            } else {

                                $("#tick_cross").fadeIn("slow")
                                        .html('<img src="' + baseUrl
                                                + 'images/tick.png" />');
                                $("#emailValidate").val("0");
                                email_error.html(" ");
                                alert("alok");
                                callback(true);
                            }

                        }
                    });

        }

        else {
            email_error.html(" ");
            callback(true);
        }

    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MvPr3/)

Or better solution with [jQuery.deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // global vars
    var form = $("#signupForm");
    var email = $("#email");
    var email_error = $("#invalid");

    // On blur
    // userEmail.blur(validateEmail);

    // On Submitting
    form.submit(function() {
                validateEmail().done(function() {
                            console.log("submit true");
                            form[0].submit();
                        }).fail(function() {
                            console.log("submit false");
                        });
                return false;
            });

    function validateEmail() {
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred()

        // if it's NOT valid
        console.log("In email");
        var a = $("#email").val();
        var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

        if (email.val() == "") {
            email_error.html("Please enter your email ");
            deferred.reject();
        }
        // if it's valid email
        else if (filter.test(a) == false) {
            email_error.html("Please enter Valid email address");
            deferred.reject();
        } else if (filter.test(a) == true) {
            console.log("elseif");
            var baseUrl = '<?= base_url() ?>';

            $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : baseUrl + "index.php/index/validateUserEmail",
                        data : "useremail=" + $("#email").val(),
                        success : function(msg) {
                            alert(msg);
                            if (msg == "1") {
                                $("#tick_cross").fadeIn("slow")
                                        .html('<img src="' + baseUrl
                                                + 'images/cross.png" />');
                                $("#emailValidate").val("1");
                                email_error
                                        .html("This email-Id already exists!");
                                deferred.reject();
                            } else {

                                $("#tick_cross").fadeIn("slow")
                                        .html('<img src="' + baseUrl
                                                + 'images/tick.png" />');
                                $("#emailValidate").val("0");
                                email_error.html(" ");
                                console.log("alok");
                                deferred.resolve();
                            }

                        }
                    });

        }

        else {
            email_error.html(" ");
            deferred.resolve();
        }

        return deferred.promise();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MvPr3/1/)

Comment: Because we do not want the default submit to proceed till the response comes back

Comment: Wow thank you so much arun it working nicelly.. i am waisting lost of time ..heartly thanks arun   :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the AJAX call takes time, but you're if statement requires an immediate return.  I'm also not sure if returning false is enough, I believe you need to capture the event and call the preventDefault() method on it...

The best thing to do would be to change your <input type="submit" /> button to <input type="button" id="submitButton" /> and then remove the `form.submit()` handler you have now entirely.  Add this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#submitButton').click(validateEmail)

})
```

and then add `$("#signupForm").submit()` to your `validateEmail()` function:

```
function validateEmail(){
    //if it's NOT valid
    alert("In email");
    var a = $("#email").val();
    var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

    if(email.val() == ""){
        email_error.html("Please enter your email ");
        return false;
    }
    //if it's valid email
    else if(filter.test(a)==false){
        email_error.html("Please enter Valid email address");
        return false;
    }
    else if(filter.test(a)==true){alert("elseif");
    var baseUrl = '<?= base_url() ?>';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl+"index.php/index/validateUserEmail",
                data: "useremail="+$("#email").val(),
                success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
                if(msg == "1")
                    {
                        $("#tick_cross").fadeIn("slow").html('<img src="'+baseUrl+'images/cross.png" />');
                        $("#emailValidate").val("1");  
                        email_error.html("This email-Id already exists!");
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        $("#tick_cross").fadeIn("slow").html('<img src="'+baseUrl+'images/tick.png" />');
                        $("#emailValidate").val("0");
                        email_error.html(" ");
                        alert("alok");
                        $("#signupForm").submit() // <--- HERE
                        return true;
                    }


                }
            });

    }

    else{
    email_error.html(" ");
    return true;
    }

}
```

You could probably clean it up a bit more now too...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the option async : false

Comment: yeah, read the docs: Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to wait untill response has finished. readyState==4

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: baseUrl+"index.php/index/validateUserEmail",
                    data: "useremail="+$("#email").val(),
                    success: function(){

                }).done(function (msg) {

alert(msg);
                    if(msg == "1")
                        {
                            $("#tick_cross").fadeIn("slow").html('<img src="'+baseUrl+'images/cross.png" />');
                            $("#emailValidate").val("1");  
                            email_error.html("This email-Id already exists!");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            $("#tick_cross").fadeIn("slow").html('<img src="'+baseUrl+'images/tick.png" />');
                            $("#emailValidate").val("0");
                            email_error.html(" ");
                            alert("alok");
                            return true;
                        }


                    }
})
.fail(function() { alert("error";
 return true;
); });
```